# Raspbian Jessie: GUI tool for ethernet settings?

Tags: networking, ethernet, raspbian-jessie

I'm glad to see the new GUI tools in Jessie.  However, the networking widget (Network Preferences) on the taskbar still perplexes me.

- Is it supposed to work?
- Can I set IP settings with it?
- Am I supposed to be able to read or write the wired adapters settings?

Are there other places to read or change the IP settings?  I noticed that the Raspberry Pi Configuration tool lets you change the hostname, but no other network settings, which is very strange.